# Change Login Manager with face recognition

Tags: boot, login

How to run My own face recognition script in the boot of the os, by verifying identity instead of a password.
- Using the Laptop camera.
- Using 4.15.0-45-generic Linux version.
Without installing any package ubuntu repository.

Comment: If you don't tell us which camera, motherboard or laptop make and model, and which version of Linux you have, we can't do a thing. Please click [edit] and add that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face Recognition isn’t technically one of the most secure ways to unlock your desktop. There is a software called [howdy](https://github.com/Boltgolt/howdy)
Using the central authentication system (PAM), this works everywhere you would otherwise need your password: log in, lock screen, `sudo`, `su`, etc

Step 1: Install via PPA on Ubuntu by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boltgolt/howdy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install howdy
```

Step 2: After installing you need to let Howdy recognise your face, by entering:

```
sudo howdy add
```

**Note:** It is recommend doing this a few times to adjust for different lighting, distance from the camera and other enviromental variables.

**Note:** If you want to install directly using a `.deb` file download the file https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy/releases/download/v2.5.1/howdy_2.5.1.deb

Comment: No, I need to lunch a saved binary file without installing any package.